# why does this code returns undefined value?

Tags: javascript, html, error-handling, syntax-error

Why is the `console.log` statement returning **undefined**?

Even though the `id` of the **tag** is **right** so it should return the value stored in the `<p>` tag?

```js
x=document.getElementById("pppp").value  //assigning the value of <p> tag to x
console.log(x)    //printing the value of x in console
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
    scale=1.0">
    <title>blabla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p id="pppp">dvshjb</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: only `input` type elements have a `value` .. a `div` is not one of these

Comment: Because there is no value of ``p`` tag... Instead of using ``.value`` use  ``.textContent`` to get **dvshjb**

Answer (score 0):

> `value` property used to access the `VALUE` of the `Form Element`.

In your case, I assume you are trying to access the text of the Element. [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) is ideal here.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("pppp").textContent;
console.log(x);
```

```html
<p id="pppp">dvshjb</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

[p](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tag does not have any value attribute. It seems you need the text content. In this case use `innerHTML`. trim() will be used to remove white space

```js
let x = document.getElementById("pppp").innerHTML.trim()
console.log(x)
```

```html
<p id="pppp">dvshjb</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
P tag does not have value property. For div, p, span, etc. you can access innerHTML.
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<title>blabla</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="pppp">dvshjb</p>
   <script>
       x=document.getElementById("pppp").innerHTML  
       console.log(x) 
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `value` to `innerHtml`

From:

```
x=document.getElementById("pppp").value;
console.log(x);
```

To:

```
x=document.getElementById("pppp").innerHTML;
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "value" property is used for inputs. You should use "innerText" as follows:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
scale=1.0">
<title>blabla</title>
</head>
<body>
   <p id="pppp">dvshjb</p>
   <script>
       x=document.getElementById("pppp").innerText //assigning the value of <p> tag to x
       console.log(x)                           //printing the value of x in console
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```